# How to run all interfaced methods?

Tags: java, interface

I want to make an api for my game and to run the api in the part you make you have to have:

```
@GameApi
public void run(){
    // what you want to do with my game
 }
```

The GameApi class is as follows:

```
public @interface GameApi {


}
```

and I don't know how to make the main method run every method in the project with a GameApi annotation. Ive also tried putting 
 `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)` 
 above the 
 `public @interface GameApi`
but when i import it, it says RetentionPolicy cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: Is the question how to compile your `GameApi` annotation with runtime retention, or how to find classes with methods that have the annotation? If the former, you just need to import both `Retention` and `RetentionPolicy`: http://pastie.org/10882762 But I think that's only part of, or tangential to, the question...

Comment: @Nathan: if I were you, instead of relying on annotations, I would define an interface that your plugins must implement, and discover them using the mechanisms described here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html

Comment: `how to make the main method run every method in the project with a GameApi annotation.` For this one, I would probably be looking for answers in Spring source code, as it also has Annotation based running of methods.

Answer (score 2):

You will do this with reflection like:

```
Object x = ...;
for (Method m : x.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
    if (m.getAnnotation(GameApi.class)!=null) {
        m.invoke(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is can't work, becose you can not run an interface but an implementation Y of an interface X.